# Set validation rule as specified using SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

DOB should not be earlier than 1/6/1948

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: Is that January 6, or 1:st of June in 1948?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [check constrains](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp)

```
CREATE TABLE parts (
    id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    dob date NOT NULL CHECK (dob <= '1948-06-01')   
);
```

Syntax may differ